# Find parent of paragraph UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to find the parent of the paragraph with the name: "ParagraphOne" (hence the RichTextBlock which has the name: "RichTextOne") but the code generates an exception.

[image: Exception]

Xaml:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <RichTextBlock x:Name="RichTextOne" Margin="30">
                <Paragraph x:Name="ParagraphOne">
                    <Run Text="This is a Text"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="btnParent" Click="btnParent_Click" Margin="30" Width="100" Height="32" Content="Find Parent"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnParent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(ParagraphOne) as UIElement;
        string pName = (parent as RichTextBlock).Name;
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("The name of parent is: " + pName);
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

a way? Thanks in advance!

The error that is generated is: Irreparable error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Comment: What's the exception? and when does it happen?

Comment: Add an image...

Comment: Don't add images of errors. Add the error message, in plain text. Plain text is searchable. Besides, there's also a call stack at the point, where the exception is raised. That information is very helpful. Post it as well.

Comment: Please also provide the call stack. Just looking at the call stack is probably going to get you a lot closer to analyzing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
RichTextBlock parent = ParagraphOne.ElementStart.Parent as RichTextBlock;
```